# Prove the derivative of the delta distribution is not a 'regular' distribution.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory, calculus-of-variations

In the terminology of Gel'fand, Generalized Functions Volume 1, a *regular* distribution, $\Lambda_f$, is one that is obtained from a locally integrable function, $f$, by integration of the function times a test function:
$$\Lambda_f(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\!f(x)\phi(x)\,dx\qquad(\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)).$$
I know that the Dirac delta distribution, defined by
$$\delta_p(\phi)=\phi(p)\qquad(\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n),\,p\in\mathbb{R}^n)$$
is not a regular distribution. For the $n=1$ case, there is a proof in Gel'fand on page 4 of Volume 1, there is this post: [How to prove that the Dirac delta is not a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115822/527829), and it is not hard to prove using the $C^\infty$-Urysohn Lemma, even for general integer $n$. (Find a mollified sequence of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions converging pointwise to the characteristic function of $\{p\}$, use Dominated Convergence and the fact that the Lebesgue measure of $\{p\}$ is zero, to get a contradiction.)

I believe that it must be true as well for all derivatives of the delta distribution. Again, for the $n=1$ case, there is this website from Professor Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/ in which one finds:

> **Exercise 11 (Derivative of the delta function)** Let [image: {d=1}]. Show that the functional [image: {\delta': f \mapsto - f'(0)}] for all test functions [image: {f}] is a distribution which does not arise from either a locally integrable function or a Radon measure. (Note how it is important here that [image: {f}] is smooth (and in particular differentiable, and not merely continuous.) The presence of the minus sign will be explained shortly.

I have been trying to prove that $\delta_p'$ is not regular in $\mathbb{R}^1$; that is, that there does not exist $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\delta_p'=\Lambda_f$, hoping that such a proof would be generalizable to $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, I haven't had any luck even with $n=1$. So my simplified first question, setting $p=0$ and $n=1$, is "why can't $\delta'$ be $\Lambda_f$ for some $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R})$?" If that can be answered, then the next question is can it be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is it true that, given any multi-index $\alpha$, there is no $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $D^\alpha\delta_p=\Lambda_f$?

In working on the $n=1$, $p=0$ case, I start with the obvious:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  -\phi'(0)=-\delta(\phi')=\delta'(\phi)=\Lambda_f(\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!f(x)\phi(x)\,dx
\qquad(\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})),
\end{equation}
and look for a sequence of test functions that generate a contradiction.
The trick of letting $\{\phi_k\}$ be a mollified sequence in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi_k$
converges pointwise to $\chi_{\{0\}}$ doesn't seem to help because it appears that $\phi'_k(0)$ will
likely have to approach $0$ and therefore not generate a contradiction. Letting $\{\phi_k\}$ just
be a bump that narrows down to $0$ but whose height remains constant, also doesn't seem to work, since again, the derivatives will be $0$ at the origin. I also hoped I might be able to make use of the fact that
if $\phi_1$ is a fixed element of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!\phi_1(x)\,dx=1,$$
then any $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ can be expressed as
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
  \phi=\phi_0+\Biggl[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!\phi(x)\,dx\Biggr]\phi_1,
\end{equation}
where $\phi_0\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and is the derivative of a function in
$C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$,
as used by Gel'fand on page 40 of Volume 1; however, I couldn't find a way where that would help.

Comment: Test with $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$ and apply the fundamental lemma of calculus.

Comment: Perhaps you can show that $f$ must be zero ae. by appropriate choice of $\phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank @MaoWao and @copper.hat for their suggestions that lead to this answer. I will rephrase the question to be more general, and then give an answer based on their suggestions.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}$
Show that, given the nonempty open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, and given various constants, that the distribution
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
  \Lambda=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq N}c_{i,\alpha}D^\alpha\delta_{p_i}\in\mathscr{D}'(\Omega)
\end{equation}
is not regular. $\alpha$ is a multi-index, and the constants are integers $m>0$, $N\geq 0$, complex $\{c_{i,\alpha}\colon i=1,\dots,m,\,\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq N\}$
(for each $i$, not all $c_{i,\alpha}$ are zero), and $\{p_1,\dots,p_m\}\subseteq\Omega$.

Proof: Let $P=\{p_1,\dots,p_m\}$ and let $\Omega_P=\Omega-P$, an open subset of $\Omega$. Let a tilde over a function variable represent the zero-extension of that function from $\Omega_P$ to $\Omega$. To reach a contradiction, suppose that there is a function $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\Omega)$, such that $\Lambda=\Lambda_f$; that is, such that for every $\psi\in\mathscr{D}(\Omega)$,
$$\Lambda(\psi)=\int_\Omega\!f\psi\,dm_\Omega\qquad(\psi\in\mathscr{D}(\Omega))$$
where $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $m_\Omega$ is the restriction of $m$ to (the Lebesgue measurable subsets of) $\Omega$. Let $f_P$ be the restriction of $f$ to $\Omega_P$. Then $f_P\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\Omega_P)$, for if $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega_P$, then it is also a compact subset of $\Omega$ so that
$\chi_Kf\in L^1(\Omega)$, and hence $\chi_Kf_P=(\chi_Kf)|_{\Omega_P}\in L^1(\Omega_P)$.
Let $\phi\in\mathscr{D}(\Omega_P)$. Then $\tilde{\phi}\in\mathscr{D}(\Omega)$ since the support of $\phi$ is contained in $\Omega_P$. We have
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\Omega_P}\!f_P\phi\,dm_{\Omega_P}
  &=\int_\Omega\!(f_P\phi)\tilde{\phantom{a}}\,dm_\Omega\\
  &=\int_\Omega\!\chi_{\Omega_P}f\tilde{\phi}\,dm_\Omega\\
  &=\int_\Omega\!f\tilde{\phi}\,dm_\Omega
  &\qquad&(\text{since $\supp\tilde{\phi}=\supp\phi\subseteq\Omega_P$})\\
  &=\Lambda(\tilde{\phi})\\
  &=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq N}c_{i,\alpha}D^\alpha\delta_{p_i}(\tilde{\phi})\\
  &=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq N}(-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert}c_{i,\alpha}\delta_{p_i}(D^\alpha\tilde{\phi})\\
  &=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq N}(-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert}c_{i,\alpha}D^\alpha\tilde{\phi}(p_i)\\
  &=0&&(\text{since $p_i\notin\supp\tilde{\phi}$}).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f_P=0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega_P$. Since $P$ is a finite set, $f=0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$, and therfore $\Lambda=0$. The inner sum in (3) is a nonzero distribution ($\Lambda_i$) whose support is $\{p_i\}$. If $\omega_i$ is an open neighborhood of
$p_i$ which does not contain $p_j$ for $j\neq i$, then there is a $\phi\in\mathscr{D}(\Omega)$ whose support is contained in $\omega_i$ such that $\Lambda_i(\phi)\neq 0$.
Furthermore, since the support of $\phi$ doesn't intersect the support of
$\Lambda_j$ for $j\neq i$, we have that $\Lambda_j(\phi)=0$ for $j\neq i$, and so
$\Lambda(\phi)=\Lambda_i(\phi)\neq 0$, a contradiction.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\delta'$ was in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$, then it would have a continuous primitive which would have the properties of the Dirac delta, which is a contradiction.

You can iterate this reasoning $n$ times to get the same result for the higher derivative $\delta^{(n)}$.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be quite a Dirac delta. Suppose $g(x)=\int_0^x\!f(t)\,dt$ is the continuous primitive. Then an integration by parts gives, for $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!g(t)\phi'(t)\,dt=\phi'(0)$. This does not imply that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!g(t)\psi(t)\,dt=\psi(0)$ for all $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$. Instead, using (2), I get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!g(t)\psi(t)\,dt=\psi(0)+\Bigl[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!\psi(t)\,dt\Bigr]\,\Bigl[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!(g-\phi_1(0))\phi_1\,dt\Bigr]$.

Comment: No, you are doing it wrong. Take $g = \int_{-\infty}^x f$ with $f=\delta'$. Then $\int_{\mathbb R} g \varphi = \int_{\mathbb R} f(y) \int_y^\infty \varphi(x)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y = -(-\varphi(0)) = \varphi(0)$

Comment: $\int_y^\infty\phi(x)\,dx$ does not necessarily have compact support. For example, that integral of a normalized unit bump is $1$ on $(-\infty,-1)$. So for the integration by parts that you have done to be valid, you would first have to show that $g$ vanishes in the following way: if $[a,b]$ is any given compact interval, then there exist $c,d$ such that $c\leq a$, $d\geq b$, and $g(c)=0=g(d)$. Even if one does that, the evaluation of the iterated integral is not valid since $\int_y^\infty\phi(x)\,dx$ may not be in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: No, $f\in L^1$ since it is locally integrable and compactly supported, so the integrals are well defined. And for compactly supported distributions of order 1, it is equivalent to take test functions $C^1$.