# Why is dirac delta function 0 except at 0

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

The dirac delta function's definition is following:[definition of dirac delta function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHMlK.jpg)

But why dirac delta function is 0 except at 0?? How can be this property derived

Comment: That is not the Dirac delta function, but the definition of the  distribution. The Dirac delta as a function is a sort of handwave-y shortcut that, if one doesn't think about it too much, functions similarly enough to the distribution to be convenient. (Even if ill-defined and strange at times.)

Comment: You mean the picture's content ('definition of dirac delta function) is definition of dirac delta function as distribution. And dirac delta as function(=0 except at 0) is heuristic thing??

Comment: Thank you @PrincessEev

Comment: Please don't link to images, especially not when there is so little content in them that you could easily write it down into your question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The dirac delta function does not exist. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115822/how-to-prove-that-the-dirac-delta-is-not-a-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distribution $T$ is said to *vanish* (or have value $0$) on a region $U$ if $T\{f\}=0$ for every test function $f$ with support on $U.$

Since this is the case for $T=\delta$ and $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ the Dirac delta distribution $\delta(x)$ is considered to vanish for $x\neq 0.$

Comment: Thank you, but why distribution is considered to vanish for x=/0??

Comment: @김형주. Isn't that clear from the definition I give? Since $\delta\{f\}=0$ for every test function $f$ with support on $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},$ by definition, $\delta$ vanishes on $U,$ i.e. for $x\neq 0.$

Comment: Thank you, but i have never seen definition which is in your explanation.. ,only mapping any test function to the value at zero. Can i see source or reference about that definition?,

Comment: @김형주. What definition are you asking for? My definition of $\delta$ is that it's "mapping any test function to the value at zero": $\delta\{f\} = f(0).$

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, then is it reasonable that 'test function with support on R-{0}'?? When test function is applied to dirac delta, isn't U=R applicable??

Comment: @김형주. The distribution $\delta$ is defined for test functions with arbitrary compact support. Some of them include origin (i.e. $0$ when working on $\mathbb R$), others don't. We can study how the distribution behaves for a subset of the test functions, e.g. for test functions not including origin in their support. For such test functions $\delta$ behaves the same way as the zero distribution. On $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ we therefore cannot differ $\delta$ from the zero distribution.

Comment: Thank you for elaborate answer. But, in material i read, they explain the test function for dirac delta is R->R function. so i'm sorry but can i see source or reference about " Some of them include origin (i.e. 0
 when working on R), others don't." in your answer

Comment: @김형주. The test functions used to define distributions are infinitely differentiable functions with compact support. This means that although they are defined on all of $\mathbb R,$ they vanish outside some compact set. You can see a couple of examples on [the Wikipedia page about "bump functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: thank you for answer, there is what i want sure. Is U domain of test function or not?

Comment: @김형주. Even if we consider only test function with support in $U=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ the domain of the test functions is still all of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Thank you as result you mean 'restriction of dirac delta to R-{0}'( dirac delta function in D'(R-{0})) right? So in integral(R-{0})( dirac delta*test function), dirac delta(x)=0. Or there is what i am wrong? @md2perpe

Comment: @김형주. That is correct. We can define the restriction of a distribution to an open region $U$ by restricting the set of test functions to those which have support in $U$. Then the restriction of $\delta$ to $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is the zero distribution.

Answer (score -3):

In many physics textbooks they tend to define the Dirac-Delta distribution as the piecewise function
$$\delta(x) = \begin{cases}0, \ \ \ &x\neq 0\\ \infty, \ \ \ &x=0.  \end{cases}$$
This is how one could possibly define this distribution in some sense.

Comment: Then, do you think we can't say 'dirac delta function is zero except 0' in terms of distribution?